# Firefox via SSH tunnel

Tags: firefox, ssh, proxytunnel

I have a question about connecting Firefox via SSH.
There are some websites like the following I need to connect 
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org

So When I connect to this website from my office, it will allow me to search documents and download without any authentication. So I guess, it because I am using the office network which has already the authentication done.

However, when I am out of office, it will ask me for authentication and I do not have username and password for the account which office uses. So I need to somehow connect to office network via SSH to access this website.

I already tried to ssh -X and open a firefox -no-remote. But it is really slow.
I would like to know if there is a solution where I can connect directly from SSH through a proxy tunnel or something. 
Also is it possible that only for some websites it should use proxy for rest others, it should use normal internet connection.

Thanks for help, 
Raj

Comment: You can try with [NX client](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ssh -D port_number office
```

Then configure your proxy in Firefox to SOCK5: localhost port_number

Should make the trick.